# What happened to Rose's Twin?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, american-dragon-jake-long

In *American Dragon: Jake Long*, during a dream state we got to know that Rose got a twin, not sure brother or sister.

[image]

But that twin never appeared again, even when Jake wished that Rose never got abducted by the Huntsclan and we see Rose as a normal girl and her family but not that twin.

Does that suggest Huntsclan abducted her twin instead of her? Do we ever get any official answer on it?